# Loading an R model in a JAR file

Tags: java, r, jar

I have a model written in R, and a 3rd party system that you can either write custom code, or import a JAR file and call functions from that.
Is there a way to load the R model into java, so I can upload and reference it rather than re-coding it?
Our modeling team develops in R, so I am trying to avoid re-doing their completed and tested efforts in the 3rd party system.
The 3rd party system is firewalled, so I cannot call out from it to a model stored elsewhere.

I have found rJava for calling Java within R, but is there an opposite technology?